# Multi-layered unordered list not displaying correctly in Kendo Template

Tags: html, kendo-ui, html-lists, kendo-template

My kendo template is as follows:

```
    <script id="instructionsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <ul style="list-style: square;">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4
                <ul style="list-style: circle;">
                    <li>Sub-Item 1</li>
                    <li>Sub-Item 2</li>
                    <li>Sub-Item 3
                        <ul style="list-style: disc;">
                            <li>Sub-Sub-Item 1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </script>
```

However, this produces the following image:

[image]

If I paste that HTML into JsBin or something, it works fine... I am wondering how I can get a multi-layered unordered list to work in a kendo template. This is a template for a kendo dialog that is set up like this:

```
            $('#instructionsContainer').kendoDialog({
                visible: false,
                title: 'Instructions',
                closable: true,
                buttonLayout: 'normal',
                modal: false,
                content: kendo.template($('#instructionsTemplate').html()), //Tried both ways to see if it would make a difference. It didn't.
                //content: $('#instructionsTemplate').html(),
                actions: [{
                    text: 'Close',
                    primary: true,
                    action: function(e){

                    }
                }]
            });
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just took your template and the code which creates your dialog, added them into a kendo app, and the dialog displays exactly as you would expect. Hence what code you've shared so far looks okay. Is it possible you have some other external CSS which is interfering?

Comment: Dang... It is possible. The application is wrapped in Salesforce, which has slds css it's applying to things. The slds already sets list style to none, which is why I explicitly state it. But other than that I'm not sure what exactly would cause the list layout to be ruined from what I've seen in the css. I may just have to hunt through it more, turning everything off to see

Comment: Ok, what I ended up finding is in JsBin, a -webkit-padding-start is added to lists inside of lists, but that isn't being added to my list in the kendo template. So all I can figure out to fix this is manually adding a -webkit-padding-start to my inner lists.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting close. If you still haven't cracked it and have a JsBin which demonstrates the problem, I'll be happy to take a look if you just share the link.